# How to assembly js libs in an angular application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, build, gulp

I'm starting my first angular application (for information, it is angular2).
I am starting to learn tools like nodejs, gulp, etc...

I have a nodejs server, which serves server stuff and front stuff.

For the front stuff, I have html, css, resources, and my js files.
For it working with angular, I have all required dependencies in node_modules.

I'm ok with typescripts management with gulp.
I have successfully managed to have my app js files concatenated in a "build" target folder.

Now, I want to copy there also my libs/dependencies, so that my index.html will have 2 script include : myapp.js and something like libs.js (minified angular and possibly any other libs).

I cannot find a way to do that. I got a result with webpack, but it minifies all my app in the libs.js file, and I want my app separate so that I can debug it in non minified js for dev mode.

Is there a way to extract from node_modules any required libs for the app, minify them and concat them in a compact libs.js ?

When I parse the node_modules, it is a huge repository (mainly due to server dependencies with stuff like gulp, mocha, ... nothing useful for the frontend), and I'm pretty sure that taking all node_modules/**/*.js and concat then is not a good idea!

Thank you for any response.

Comment: You simply need to take the required js / css file from the npm pack and put a reference to them in your index.html file, you shouldn't need to create a gulp task for this.

Comment: That would mean having references to `node_modules` folder inside the frontend html : this folder is not available, and I saw that it is a bad practice.

I would need to copy all required js/css to the `build` folder.

Comment: It's bad practise to check in your libraries to a VCS but it isn't at all "bad" to have a reference to a file in your index.html from a `node_modules` directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [browserify](http://browserify.org/). It allows you to use the `require()` function like you do in node.js. There is also a [gulp plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-browserify).

So for example if you want to use lodash, first you run `npm install --save lodash`, then in your javascript you will have:

```
var _ = require('lodash');
// from here you can use lodash like normal
```

The files can be both compiled by your node server or precompiled by gulp.

Once compiled, the files will be bundled with every dependency you declared using `require()`

#### EDIT

To answer your comment, if you want to export a separate file including only the libraries, you can do this

libs.js

```
window._ = require('lodash');
window.$ = require('jquery');
// any other library
```

app.js

```
// here you can use the libraries like normal
console.log(_);
console.log($);
```

index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
```

But personally I prefer to have only one file with everything bundled.

Comment: I am trying browserify.

I could exclude some packages, but it still packages the app itself.
I still cannot find a way for the moment to have a `libs.js` on one hand, and my `app.js` on the other hand.